# RIA override metadata on the client

Tags: silverlight, metadata, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, ria

I have an entity with the following fields in the server side metadata class:

```
Partial Friend Class CustomerMetadata
    <Required()> _
    <Display(Order:=1, Name:="First Name")> _
    Public Property FirstName As String

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Order:=2, Name:="Last Name")> _
    Public Property LastName As String

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Order:=3, Description:="Phone")> _
    Property DisplayPhone As String

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Order:=4, Name:="Email Address")> _
    Public Property EmailAddress As String
End Class
```

Now in the client, I want to swap the display order of the Phone and Email address fields in a datagrid, so I create a new client side CustomerMetadata class like such:

```
Partial Friend Class CustomerMetadata
    <Required()> _
    <Display(Order:=4, Description:="Phone")> _
    Property DisplayPhone As String

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Order:=3, Name:="Email Address")> _
    Public Property EmailAddress As String
End Class
```

The client doesn't pick up the overridden display order. Any ideas on how to override the Display attribute in the client side metadata class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to override the metadata in the client that you set on the server.

In particular, the RIA Services concept of metadata classes is a server-side one - and only used when using Entity Framework with the model-first-approach where you have the designer create your entity classes). The attributes you put on the metadata classes on the server will be auto-generated during build as attributes on the actual entities on the client.

Since the ordering attributes are the only way I know of to control the `DataGrid` ordering when using auto-generated columns, I can only think of two ways to evade the issue:

1. Specify the columns in your grid explicitly (in the end you probably have to anyway for a host of reasons, auto-generated columns are rarely sufficient in practice) or
2. use the same ordering in both the client and the server entities.

(For the sake of completion I should mention that you can also fiddle with the way RIA Services client code is auto-generated, but that would be inappropriate for the problem you're having.)

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured, but I hoping . . . :)